# Cant get text while webscraping a site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the part where it says Avvisami on this website: https://www.nike.com/it/launch/t/womens-air-jordan-3-sp-a-ma-maniere
to appear as a string on my code. Every time I try anything it doesn't work. This is the part of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\mainuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/it/launch/t/womens-air-jordan-3-sp-a-ma-maniere')

instock = (driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ncss-btn-primary-dark  btn-lg'))

print(instock)
```

and in that, this is the part I think I need to change:

```
instock = (driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ncss-btn-primary-dark  btn-lg'))

print(in stock)
```

I've been trying to fix it for an hour or so but I just can't wrap my head around how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a text from a list of elements. Iterate it and use `.text`:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ncss-btn-primary-dark.btn-lg")
for el in elems:
    print(el.text)
```

All of these elements are buttons.

Answer (score 1):

```
instock = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ncss-btn-primary-dark.btn-lg").text
print(instock)
```

Multiple class names should be used with css selector and to grab the text just use .text and then place it in your variable.

Comment: It's almost correct, just this css locator is not unique. That's why find_elements_by_css_selector is the best case for it.